# Unable to add attachment to the mail with html template

Tags: email, email-template, send-email

Users are unable to add the files to the mail while using an HTML template. Below is the screenshot which attachment icon being disabled once the HTML template is selected.[image]

Comment: There's no restriction that I know of. E.g., if I use a HTML template while sending an Email from Chatter feed, I can still add attachments. You need to be more specific here as from where you are trying to add the email, etc.

Comment: On contact, detail page I have an activity section where I can compose mail and select templates. I can add attachments in my dev org but in my sandbox, I'm unable to add the files to the mail when an HTML template is selected.